# Get Object from a Collection to another form

Tags: vb.net, forms

In my second Form, I have a Collection of an Object which I add when I need.

When I want to access to the first Object in that Collection for example, from another Form. It returns me nothing: when I do `form2.list.Count`, I have 0. What I understood from this, is the Collection is Null.

But in the second form (the Form where I created that Collection), if I do `form2.list.Count`, I have the correct count and I have access to all the data.

I made sure that Collection was Public but still, I don't know where is the problem.

How can I solve this ?

Edit:

```
Public Class Form2

    Public mycarlist As New carlist

    Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click

        dim mycar as car

        'I have other textbox but for simplicity, I only put one
        mycar = new car(Me.TextBox1.Text) 

        mycarlist.Add(mycar)

        ' Here everything works, I have the correct count and brand
        Form1.TextBox1.Text = mycarlist.count
        Form1.TextBox2.Text = mycarlist(0).brand

        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

And it's from this Form (Form1) that I want to access to this list:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub testbt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tesbt.Click
        Me.TextBox3.Text = Form2.mycarlist.Count

        'For example a Property that I want to print
        Me.TextBox4.Text = Form2.mycarlist(0).Brand

    End Sub

    Private Sub openform2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles openform2.Click
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

In the Form1, the TextBox1 returns me 0

And when the program will execute this line `Me.TextBox2.Text = Form2.mycarlist(0).Brand`, I have this error:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException from `carlist`.

Comment: Please share the reproducible erroneous code.

Comment: Edit your question with the link below the question to add the relevant code. We should not have to guess how you are creating the list, what the object is, and how you are attempting to access the list. Are you using vb's default forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assertion that the collection is null is incorrect because otherwise you'd receive a NullReferenceException to the effect of:

> Run-time exception (line -1): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

VB.NET does some funky stuff when it comes to accessing forms. My guess is that you're attempting to get the wrong instance of Form2 and VB.NET is creating a new instance of the Form behind the scenes.

Could you show how it is that you're creating Form2? It may be as simple as referencing the correct instance of the Form. E.g.:

```
Private frm2 As Form2 = New Form2()
' user adds item(s) to list
frm2.list.Count
```

Comment: @PandaBear instead, try to create a new instance like I did and then call `frm2.Show()`

Comment: well, I have another problem. When I want to reopen the form2, I have this error `System.ObjectDisposedException`

Comment: Generally you'd wrap the form creating in a Using statement, are you showing the form like a modal?

Comment: Do you mean `ShowDialog()` ? If so, no, I used `Show()`

Comment: Not necessarily ShowDialog I was asking more so if it being used within the same scope where a Using statement could be applied. Because if not then you'll be forced to dispose of the object when it is hidden.